# Execute Package Task on a external IS server

Tags: sql, ssis

We have recently started moving our development environment to a second data center. We have an Integration Services Server and an SQL server at both locations. We stage data from customers at our main data center, load it to a production warehouse and a development warehouse at our secondary server through SSIS. The problem I'm having is launching child packages that are stored on that development IS server are still using the main IS servers resources when launched from a parent package on the main server. This isn't ideal because of network latency caused by the physical distance between the servers (it's our DR site). This forces our load times to development to be 2x-4x what it is to our production site.

I launch it as a child package instead of using dtexec because I pass variables to the child to create connections/logging purposes.

I'm pretty sure I'll have to start with the ExecuteOutOfProcess property but I haven't been able to find any hints beyond that. Has anyone found a solution for this type of execution besides a lot of custom coding?

Comment: I have a similar situation, I always run packages on the SQL Server when possible, because performance suffers anywhere else.  Also, I don't follow your reasoning for not using dtexec, dtexec doesn't prevent variable use.